# Почему звук зацикливается и играет постоянно?

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

Пишу небольшую игру в xcode  с помощью SpriteKit, решил добавить звуки, тоесть например когда пользователь нажимает на экран герой делает мах мечом и должен проиграться соответствующий звук, я это реализовал так:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let swoshSound = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "action.wav")
    self.addChild(swoshSound)       
}
```

Звук есть, только появилась проблема - он не прекращается а играет как будто в цикле. 
Я попробовал использовать такую функцию как:

```
scene!.audioEngine.stop()
```

Но тогда почему то звук не играет вообще, видимо сразу прекращается как только создается. Также я пробовал делать так:

```
    sleep(1)
    scene!.audioEngine.stop()
```

Звук появлялся 1 раз как нужно, но команда sleep как бы погружает в сон всю игру и если при каждом нажатия она будет на секунду останавливаться то это будет как то не то. Помогите пожалуйста как решить это проблему? Может есть какие то встроенные методы или как это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать

```
let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("file.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
run(sound)
```